# Can we get YouTube video embedding enabled?

Tags: feature-request

There are some great [animated visualizations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56778/753) and general [how-to videos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48360/753) linked to in various questions and answers on this site.

I noticed that on some other StackExchange sites (e.g. [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-can-i-beat-level-3-15-in-angry-birds/3749#3749), [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/6142)) they [allow YouTube videos to be embedded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189) and thought this might be something we could benefit from as well.

Can (and should) we enable that feature on GIS.SE? I think video is an important medium for both visualization and as a learning tool in GIS.

Comment: This might be a good request to stack exchange admin after the 2 new moderators are up and running after 30th April 2013. Though linking to video sites is just on click away which is the current way and works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good idea but there should be some restrictions and rules for linking videos. However we consider that it makes people to guide easy way with sharing videos rather than writing.

Besides no one can guarantee that anybody share illegal and abusing material or violating the rights of the user on this site.

So it should be discussed anyway!

Comment: I don't think the potential for abuse is high and we already have good moderation tools so if there is abuse it would be handled like anything else. IMO the benefits far outweigh the risks. If a picture is worth 1000 words is a video worth 10,000? Probably not but still :)

Comment: I completely agree with your opinion but there should be some rules. :)

Comment: I don't know of any rules per se on the other sites in which embedding is enabled. I think the common sense rule would apply - it should be work safe, GIS-related, and contribute to the question or answer.